# Is the code actually executed when using a Mockery spy?

Tags: laravel, mockery

I am trying to write some tests with a [Mockery Spy](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/spies.html). However, it doesn't seem like the "spied upon" code is executed when I'm using a spy.

Is the code actually executed when using a Mockery spy?

Here is what I tested:

```php
// In my test:
$spy = $this->spy(FeedManager::class);

// Controller
resolve(FeedManager::class)->createResponse();

// FeedManger::createResponse()
public static function createResponse(Builder $builder)
{
  dd("here i am"); // this never gets called unless I remove the spy
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the "spy code" is not supposed to run. Found this quote from [the docs](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html).

> The `\Mockery::spy()` method call is actually a shorthand for calling
> `\Mockery::mock()->shouldIgnoreMissing()`. The shouldIgnoreMissing
> method is a “behaviour modifier”.